# Is there a feature in ExtJS like dojo.load?

Tags: extjs, dojo

I was wondering if there is a feature in ExtJS where I can just load the individual components that I need. For example, dojo uses dojo.load() and then I specify in the method what component I want to load, be it fx, numeric or other cool parts.

Comment: perhaps you mean dojo.require?

Comment: Yeah, stuff like that and a modular approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in support for this.  However, Doug Hendricks has a UX called [$JIT](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?21681-ext-basex-JIT-4.0-adapter-extensions-Ajax-enhancements-and-more.&p=225658#post225658) (Just In Time) that is supposed to add such functionality (haven't tried it myself).  You might check it out (along with the rest of his ext-basex stuff).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the closest.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS uses AJAX in numerous ways.  There is a class called Ext.data.Store class that you can specify a URL that in turn references a static class called Ext.Ajax.  These data stores are typically used to house data for everything from data grids to combo boxes.

Here's some an example of how an individual component's data could be loaded.

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
      reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
          root: root,
          fields: [ {name: 'fullname'}
                    ,{name: 'first'}
          ],
      })

      idIndex: 0 // id for each record will be the first element
      autoLoad: true,  
      proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
          url: getNames.php
      })
}); 
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
       id: 'myID',
       name: 'names',
       store: myStore,
       displayField: 'first',
       valueField   :'fullname'

});
```

The Ext.Ajax class can also be used directly.

```
// Basic request
   Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: 'foo.php',
      success: someFn,
      failure: otherFn,
      headers: {
          'my-header': 'foo'
          },
      params: { foo: 'bar' }
   });

// Simple ajax form submission
Ext.Ajax.request({
    form: 'some-form',
    params: 'foo=bar'
 });
```

Comment: Hi I am talking about general components of the framework, for instance if I only wanted to use Ext.Ajax I wouldn't like to have to call the whole library with for instance Ext.Grid.